# If a SAAS product exposes an API using data licensed under "Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International", do clients have to also attribute?

Tags: creative-commons

If a SAAS product partially uses data distributed under the "Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike 4.0 International License", and makes that data available through an API. Do clients of the company, who consume the API, need to also attribute in their documentation/advertising?

This question [Can work licensed under a Creative Commons license WITHOUT ShareAlike attribute be republished UNADAPTED without the CC license?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/9483/can-work-licensed-under-a-creative-commons-license-without-sharealike-attribute) appears to suggest that it would, and perhaps all of the data with it.

Comment: What aspect of the data causes it to be subject to copyright protection?  Is it photographs, sound recordings, literary works, or similar?

Comment: IP geolocation data and similar information